# XSLT wrap element and following-sibling text

Tags: xslt

Kindly help me to wrap the img.inline element with the following sibling text comma (if comma exists):

```
text <img id="1" class="inline" src="1.jpg"/> another text.
text <img id="2" class="inline" src="2.jpg"/>, another text.
```

Should be changed to:

```
text <img id="1" class="inline" src="1.jpg"/> another text.
text <span class="img-wrap"><img id="2" class="inline" src="2.jpg"/>,</span> another text.
```

Currently, my XSLT will wrap the img.inline element and add comma inside the span, now I want to remove the following comma.

```
text <span class="img-wrap"><img id="2" class="inline" src="2.jpg"/>,</span>
, <!--remove this extra comma--> another text.
```

My XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="//img[@class='inline']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="starts-with(following-sibling::text(), ',')">
        <span class="img-wrap">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
          <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </span>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:copy>

  <!-- checking following-sibling::text() -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::text()" mode="commatext"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- here I want to match the following text, if comma, then remove it -->  
<xsl:template match="the following comma" mode="commatext">
  <!-- remove comma -->
</xsl:template>
```

Is my approach is correct? or is this something should be handled differently? pls suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are copying the `img` and the embedding the `span` within that. Also, you do `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>` which will select child nodes of `img` (or which there are none). And for the attributes it will end add them to the `span`.

You don't actually need the `xsl:choose` here as you can add the condition to the `match` attribute.

```
<xsl:template match="//img[@class='inline'][starts-with(following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()], ',')]">
```

Note I have changed the condition as `following-sibling::text()` selects ALL text elements that follow the `img` node. You only want to get the node immediately after the `img` node, but only if it is a text node.

Also, trying to select the following text node with `xsl:apply-templates` is probably not the right approach, assuming you have a template that matches the parent node which selects all child nodes (not just `img` ones). I am assuming you were using the identity template here.

Anyway, try this XSLT instead

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="no" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//img[@class='inline'][starts-with(following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()], ',')]">
  <span class="img-wrap">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  </span>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[starts-with(., ',')][preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::img]/@class='inline']">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 2)" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```